# Customization of scrollbar

Tags: wpf, combobox, scroll, wpf-controls

[image]

Hi

I want my combo-box to look like the above picture . I have tried a lot of ways but didn't get successful. Can anyone tell me any website or code which can style my combo-box like the above picture.

I have made the default scrollbar of Aero-theme but, i want its pop-up to be bigger than width of combo-box . secondly the scroll bar in both ends .How can i do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend starting from a [Theme](http://wpfthemes.codeplex.com/) and modifying it to fit your needs.  That will give you a basis for how to implement scrollbar templates, and it should be reasonably easy to achieve your result.  Otherwise, if you have access to Expression Blend, it can help you to create a custom Control Template for your scrollbar as well.

To use a Theme, simply include the Xaml file in your project and reference the Xaml from your Application.

```
<Application x:Class="MyApp.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>

        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Themes/ExpressionDark.xaml" />
...
```

This will replace the templates for all controls in your app.  If you only want the scrollbar, comment out the rest of the file and keep the Style and ControlTemplate that is specific to ScrollBar.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15087090/customizing-the-scrollviewer-in-wpf please see this, i use the code but this is giving the error " </dropShadow:SystemDropShadowChrome> not found".